# gdata dotnet client library for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, photo

I Installed the Google Data API SDK to get gdata dotnet client library for .NET but I when I m trying to include the dll it says its not compiled with Windows Runtime. So what is the possible solution I could do so that I can use the Google Data API in WP7 Application. I have searched many websites but could not get any solid clues or detailed steps to do it.

If somebody can provide me the proper steps it would be great

thanks
mugu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Data API .NET library is compiled for the desktop CLR. You will need to download the source and compile it as a Windows Phone Library (or Silverlight library) to use it with a Windows Phone application.

Google does not distribute a WP7/SL binary for the library.

Comment: Where can I find the instructions or some examples on how to compile the source code as WP library. I tried downloading the source code and compile it for windows application. But I m getting lots of errors.

Comment: You'll need to work through the potential differences in the frameworks.

Comment: You should consider using the Google APIs client library for .NET. All the generated packages are available using NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google.apis&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance).

Comment: @pleyal - You should point out that you are the maintainer for those packages in the interest of full disclosure. Your original comment implies that they are official packages.